# OpenModalDialogCommand without site configuration permission

Tags: ajax, modal-dialogs

I have a custom module in Drupal 8.9.9 to open a form in a modal dialog with `OpenModalDialogCommand`.

The `custom_modal.routing.yml` file has:

```
custom_modal.open_modal_form:
  path: '/modal_form/{title}/{vocabulary}'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Modal Form'
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_modal\Controller\CustomModalController::openModalForm'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
  options:
    parameters:
      title:
        type: String
      vocabulary:
        type: String
```

And the `CustomModalController.php`:

```
  public function openModalForm($title, $vocabulary) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();

    $values = array('vid' => $vocabulary);

    $term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
      ->create($values);

    $form = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getFormObject('taxonomy_term', 'default')
      ->setEntity($term);

    $term_form =  \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);

    $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($title, $term_form, ['width' => '800']));

    return $response;
  }
```

My theme has the following dependencies:

```
global-scripts:
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupal.dialog.ajax
```

And I have even added the following to my `custom_modal.module`:

```
function custom_modal_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id, $no_js_use = FALSE) {
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.ajax';
}
```

Nevertheless, whereas everything works fine when I use the site administrator, when using a simple authenticated user the modal dialog does not open and I get the following error:

```
There was an HTTP AJAX error.
HTTP Result Code: 403
Below is the information on debugging.
Path: /modal_form/Create/style
StatusText: Forbidden
ResponseText: {"message": "The administer site configuration permission is required."}"
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: And when you try to open a simple custom form like that? Does that work?

Comment: Hi, checking what you said, the problem is not related to the code (I was having problems with the server), so the posted code works correctly. In fact, `core/drupal.dialog.ajax` is not necessary. Thank you and sorry!